# Query to update the column of second table based on newly generated id of first table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables company_types and companies_profiles.
company_types_id of company_types and company_type_id of companies_profiles has one to many relationship.

Few new entries has been added recently to company_types table for platform_country_mapping_id bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21 with all the similar name what we had earlier for 8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f. So now i have to update companies_profiles table's company_type_id column with newly generated company_types_id in company_types table.

**company_types**

```
company_types_id    name                        platform_country_mapping_id     
1                   name1                       8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f
2                   name2                       8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f
3                   name3                       8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f

101                 name1                       bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21
102                 name2                       bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21
103                 name3                       bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21
```

**companies_profiles**

```
company_id  company_type_id             platform_id                             platform_name
149         1                       8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f        platformName1
150         2                       8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f        platformName1
185         3                       8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f        platformName1

248         1                       bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21        platformName2
249         2                       bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21        platformName2
250         1                       bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21        platformName2
251         3                       bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21        platformName2
```

Required result of updated **companies_profiles** table

```
company_id  company_type_id             platform_id                             platform_name
149         1                       8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f        platformName1
150         2                       8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f        platformName1
185         3                       8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f        platformName1

248         101                     bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21        platformName2
249         102                     bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21        platformName2
250         101                     bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21        platformName2
251         103                     bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21        platformName2
```

Below is the query what i have tried and works fine for at least one entry.

```sql
Update companies_profiles 
  set company_type_id= (Select company_types_id 
                        from company_types 
                        where name = (Select name 
                                      from company_types 
                                      where company_types_id = (Select company_type_id 
                                                                from companies_profiles 
                                                                where platform_name='platformName2' 
                                                                limit 1 offset 0)
                                     ) 
                          and platform_country_mapping_id='bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21'
                      ) 
where company_type_id = (Select company_type_id 
                         from companies_profiles 
                         where platform_name='platformName2' limit 1 offset 0) 
and platform_id='bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21'
```

Comment: I tried to format your post to a normal state and if you take your query, you will see that it has incorrect syntax in the last row (where company_type_id =  platform_id = [id value]). Please check your query sintaxis and edit it to a working state

Comment: i have updated the query.

Comment: Why did you add the `mysql` tag? Please don't tag databases not involved

Comment: I see no data mapping old type 1 to new 101 etc.

Comment: In companies_profiles table for company_id 148 company_type_id should be 101 because  earlier company_type_id of companies_profiles was 1 and corresponding name in company_types with platform_country_mapping_id 8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f is name1. Again we have to look for company_types_id in company_types where name is name1 and platform_country_mapping_id is bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21 which is 101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single query for name is not possible so i wrote the seprate query for each name as below:

```
Update companies_profiles set company_type_id=(Select company_types_id from company_types where name= 
'name1' and platform_country_mapping_id='bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21') where company_type_id=
(Select company_types_id from company_types where name= 
'name1' and platform_country_mapping_id='8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f') 
and platform_id='bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21';

Update companies_profiles set company_type_id=(Select company_types_id from company_types where name= 
'name2' and platform_country_mapping_id='bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21') where company_type_id=
(Select company_types_id from company_types where name= 
'name2' and platform_country_mapping_id='8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f') 
and platform_id='bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21';

Update companies_profiles set company_type_id=(Select company_types_id from company_types where name= 
'name3' and platform_country_mapping_id='bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21') where company_type_id=
(Select company_types_id from company_types where name= 
'name3' and platform_country_mapping_id='8cb794b5-c37a-4c19-880d-355f65c1d33f') 
and platform_id='bc82e358-919d-44f2-aa35-24416a052c21';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).